# Automate SMTP Using Python

Tags: python, unix, automation, terminal

I'm just beginning to use python to automate sending emails through gmail. I have gotten the whole process to work just typing directly into the command line, but now I want to automate the process (i.e. send emails at regular intervals). I have gotten the first part to work, where I get a connection with the SMTP server.

```
os.system("openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -crlf -ign_eof")
```

Now I want to get it so that it will type and run the following commands within that connection:

```
os.write("HELO", os.linesep)
os.write("AUTH LOGIN", os.linesep) ... And so on
```

I have tried this using the write commands as well as the os.system command, but neither seems to actually insert the text into this window. Could someone with perhaps more linux and terminal skills be able to help with this? Also, it seems that the time.sleep doesn't work when all of these system processes are running. How can I get around that?

Comment: Python does have a [`smtplib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#module-smtplib) module to provide an SMTP client. It doesn't make sense to use `openssl` directly if your goal is to use Python.

Comment: I have tried smtplib, but it has not worked with connections to gmail. If you can provide working code that will establish a connection, post it and I'll check it out. However, I have found that openssl is the only way I have even managed to get a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the SMTP client implementation from the standard library: http://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib

```
import smtplib
smtp_client = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtp_client.starttls()
smtp_client.login(username, password)
```

If you are using 2-factor-authentication, you need to create an application specific password to use.

Comment: I think gmail is different from most SMTP servers in that you can't just follow the regular login steps. I think it's specially encoded, so the smtplib does not work. Does that code work for you?

Comment: Yes, the code does work for me. You can't use your standard password if you do 2-factor-authentication, but that's it.

Comment: Can you post any stacktraces or errors you get using smtplib?

Comment: Sure! Here's the code I'm running (but modified to exclude encoded passwords and email addresses) import smtplib
smtp_client = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtp_client.starttls()
smtp_client.login("encoded email here", "encoded password here")
smtp_client.sendmail("email address","to"," message ")

Comment: The error is as follows: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smtplibtest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "/Users/Connor/Documents/BuildTech/email.py", line 15, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SMTP'

Comment: Your main code is in `email.py`, right? That is picked up when smtplib is trying to `import email.utils`. Try renaming that, remove the email.py[co] files if they exist, try again.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the subprocess module to do what you want. You cannot just "os.write", you need to "write" to the process's standard input and output.

```
command = ['openssl', 's_client', '-starttls smtp', '-connect smtp.gmail.com:587', '-crlf', '-ign_eof']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=PIPE) # Success!
p.write("HELO", "MYNAME")
```

etc.

Comment: For some reason, I had an issue with stdin=PIPE. Is there more to it than just this?

Comment: try subprocess.PIPE instead of PIPE

Comment: Appears to solve that problem. But the write function returns this error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestGmailConnection.py", line 9, in <module>
    p.write("HELO", "MYNAME")
AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'write'
unknown option -starttls smtp
usage: s_client args

Comment: ah Im sorry I've made another mistake :P You need to use p.communicate("HELO MYNAME") http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html also your command seems to have issues.